# How to mock a method and see if it was called at all?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-mock

I have a method that ends like this:

```
def compute(self, is_send_emails, test_email_address):
    ...
    if is_send_emails:
          self.sendEmails(uniq_email_pids=uniq_email_pids,
                                    test_email_address=test_email_address)
    else:
          logging.debug("send_emails = False - No emails were sent out.")
```

How should I unit test this case, where `is_send_emails` parameter is false and I have to assert that `sendEmails()` was not called.

I thought I should mock `self.sendEmails()` to see if it was called at all.

```
def test_x(self):
    with mock.patch('apps.dbank.x.sendEmails') as sendEmails_mock:
```

But now I am stuck, how to check that.  This [site](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.assert_called_with) explains the different asserts I could use, but none of them seems appropriate. Should I use `assert_called_with`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test that your mock was **not** called, just test the [`called` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.called) is `False`:

```
self.assertFalse(sendEmails_mock.called)
```